# Spark dataframe to csv file saving as part

Tags: apache-spark

Hi i have this code that saves dataframe into cvs locally on system and i keep getting a directory names myfile.csv/part-0000.gz, part-0001.gz .... i just want a cvs file. here my code

```
String current = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
groupedMessages.write()
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
  .save("/finance_reports/myfile.csv");
```

}

Comment: if you want a single `csv` file and your data isn't too large you can save it  on one worker as a single file by: `groupedMessages.coalesce(1).write.format("...")....`

Comment: thanks for response i still only get part-0000.gz not a csv file